# Close Realm instance, when i use Realm query with RxJava

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java

when I return query results as observable, where I must close realm instance? Example:

```
public Observable<RealmResults<Weather>> getWeatherForecast() {
       final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 

       return realm.where(Weather.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
                .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of cases:

1. [`doOnCompleted`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operator:

   ```
   realm.where(Weather.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
           .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
           .first()
           .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    realm.close();
                };
           })
   ```
2. Inside `Subscriber`'s `onCompleted` method:

   ```
   getWeatherForecast()
           .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted() {
                   realm.close();
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable e) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {
               }
           });
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I have other question, may be you know: I don't know what way use, use ReamlResults with async queries and change listeners or use rxjava, when I will work with recycle view for example?

Comment: For me, onComplete callback not call, when I use it, why?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2010 -> Just use `first()` operator as you want to close connection after getting the result.

Comment: Okey, may I close realm instance on doOnUnsubscribe()?

Comment: Try it. I have not tested such case.

Comment: May be I found error in your case. In realm docs: "Realm instances are reference counted, which means that if you call getInstance() twice in a thread, you will also have to call close() twice as well." When we get instance in onComplete and close it, we close only new instance and old, wich i use in getWeatherForecast method not closed. I'm right?

Comment: yes you are right. You have to keep reference to `Realm` somewhere else to get always the same reference.

Comment: I don't think `onCompleted` is ever called unless you use `.first()`, which wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: So if I dont use first(), how can i close it?